# Make a custom field auto clickable

Tags: php, wordpress

I am building a directory site and I have a custom field for the website address. I would like this website address to automatically be made into a link, so that I don't need to go into each one and add the html to create a link. This functionality exists out of the box for comments in wordpress.  I have found the code that can make it work for the content:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'make_clickable', 12 );
```

But I don't know how to target my custom field. I've tried searching but don't think I know enough php to phrase my search properly. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: What CMS are you building your website on?

Comment: Is it WordPress?

Comment: Yes, it's wordpress

Comment: If it's WP, then what do you mean for it to be click-able; click-able from where? You need to EDIT your question and give more details, I am afraid.

Comment: How have you created this custom field? Did you use a plugin?

Comment: I used a box within the thesis theme: https://www.byobwebsite.com/plugins/boxes-plugins-for-thesis-theme-2-1/byob-post-meta-fields-extended-box/

Comment: Read: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/255645/opening-links-in-new-tab-using-add-filter-the-content-make-clickable/255657

Comment: @PawanKumar this link is about making a link open in a new tab, which isn't what I was asking.